# VS 2022 Debugger causing System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Safe handle has been closed.'

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging, safehandle

I have a single-threaded application in NET6.0 with VS2022. With the debugger, I randomly get this exception:

System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Safe handle has been closed. Object name: 'SafeHandle'.'

It happens only with my class that wraps a SerialPort. I have an equivalent class which wraps TcpClient and has no issue.

Here's an example code

```
class SerialDriver
{
    byte[] buf;
    SerialPort port;

    void Connect(); // port.Open() + a few writes and reads
    void Disconnect(); // port.Close()
    int Read(); // Synchronous read
}

void Main()
{
    SerialDriver s = new SerialDriver("COM5");
    s.Connect();

    // Using the debugger from here on causes SafeHandle Exception,
    // even on lines that do not referecnce the serial port at all.

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int len = s.Read();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
    s.Disconnect();
}
```

- "Step Over" or "Step Into" - About 2 or 3 clicks before exception
- "Continue" between breakpoints - About 7 to 10 before exception
- No Breakpoints, or no debugger - No exception.

Has anyone encountered an issue with the debugger?

Comment: A silent exception that is already handled by SerialPort but the debugger catches it because of your settings? You just don't get to see them without the debugger but they are still there.

Comment: Thank you. The call stack contains only .NET lines, nothing from my code. Something called System.IO.Ports.dll!System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.AsyncFSCallback. What settings would you recommend looking at? I am not familiar with these settings.

Comment: As a starter on the Exceptions Settings page open the Context Menu on the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" node and click "Restore Defaults".

Comment: Hmm, no change in restore to defaults. I'll try running from a different machine and see what happens.

Comment: Hi, could you please share the actual minimalize code that be able to reproduce? The class looks like interface

Comment: Hmm, in trying to create a minimal code to reproduce, I'm finding that it does not occur with a stripped down implementation. Clearly there's something wrong with my code, here. I'll keep working to to find out where it's going wrong. It's really strange that only the debugger catches it.

Comment: OK, turns out, it was all because I overrode a ToString() method in a way that made calls to the SerialPort. If I comment it out, the problem goes away. The debugger seems to call ToString in my "Locals" watch. Maybe the call is made asynchronously? In any case, it doesn't seem wise to turn ToString() into a sluggish method. I think I've seen something like that before. Thanks for the guidance